# WPF Overriding Current Culture is not reflecting in all controls or in UI elements

Tags: c#, wpf

TextBlock is showing as "NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSizes" with currentculture format. But DataGrid is showing in different format for a column bound to "double" from query. What errors i am doing?

```
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-IN");

        NumberFormatInfo myNumberFormatInfo = new CultureInfo("en-IN", true).NumberFormat;
        int[] myGroupSize = { 3, 2, 2, 2 };
        myNumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSizes = myGroupSize;
        myNumberFormatInfo.CurrencyGroupSizes = myGroupSize;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat = myNumberFormatInfo;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat = myNumberFormatInfo;

        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its been solved by using System.Reflection;

```
        var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        var language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(culture.IetfLanguageTag + "-current");
        var type = typeof(XmlLanguage);
        const BindingFlags kField = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
        type.GetField("_equivalentCulture", kField).SetValue(language, culture);
        type.GetField("_compatibleCulture", kField).SetValue(language, culture);
        if (culture.IsNeutralCulture) culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture.Name);
        type.GetField("_specificCulture", kField).SetValue(language, culture);
        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(language));
```